# FTP File Download in Hybrid App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ftp, sencha-touch

I am developing Hybrid App using Sencha Touch 2.4 and Cordova. Need to download file from ftp server, But i can't find any plugin for both Android and ios.

I tried to open FTP URL in appInBrowser using Cordova, But i am getting Webpage can't find (May be FTP not supported in WebView ?). Same URL works in desktop browser.

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('ftp://xxxx:xxxx@support.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xxx.ipa', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html) for iOS.

And a link here for [Android](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/).

There appear to be numerous tutorials available from a quick Google search, I suggest following some of these:

androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/android-ftp-client-tutorial-with.html

java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1223

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I can write a cordova plugin that supports Android and iOS using those tutorials. But that's my last option. I am really looking for already written Plugin or a way to do it using WebView (InAppBrowser).

Comment: Any option to do this with `InAppBrowser`?